# cherrypy (python httpserver), how to post xml file in body

Tags: post, response, cherrypy

I want cherrypy to return a xml file in response body in post.

In POST(self), I read a xml file and modify some of the attributes and do these things:

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8'
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Length'] = len(data)

cherrypy.response.body = data
cherrypy.log("response body is: %s" % cherrypy.response.body)
```

When the client calls, it won't get the body.

curl waits for few seconds and returns this:

curl: (18) transfer closed with 4018 bytes remaining to read

Not sure if I am doing the right thing to send the data back to the client.
I took wireshark trace and I am not seeing any data getting sent out from the server.
Can someone please suggest?

Comment: are you sure you want to modify your response body like this? i got a bad feeling about this. why don't you do an ajax post request where you send your file, modify the data and get the modified file sent back to you?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have made this work. Earlier I was calling another function to set above mentioned values. Once I moved them in POST function, things started working. I am not sure what difference do it make. Now, I am setting them this way:

```
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8' 
cherrypy.response.headers['Content-Length'] = len(data) 

return data
```